# Boost serialization cope of different versions

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, boost-serialization

I'm doing serialization with boost:

```
bool saveParams(std::string filename)
{
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
    std::ofstream ofs(filename.c_str());
    if(ofs.is_open() == false) return false;
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive xml(ofs);

    xml << make_nvp("Param1", param1value);
    xml << make_nvp("Param2", param2value);
    xml << make_nvp("Param3", param3value);
    xml << make_nvp("Param4", param4value);
}
```

Loading is done with:

```
bool loadParams(std::string filename)
{
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
    if(ifs.is_open() == false) return false;
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive xml(ifs);

    xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param1value);
    xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param2value);
    xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param3value);
    xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param4value);
}
```

Now I want to add Param5. **How to add aditional version info and cope it when loading?** I've found in docs how to do it when class is serialized with `BOOST_CLASS_VERSION(serialized_class, version)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I will present my ugly solution as an answer. When better solution will appear I will accept it.

I've coped versions with exceptions:

```
bool loadParams(std::string filename)
{
    using boost::serialization::make_nvp;
    std::ifstream ifs(filename.c_str());
    if(ifs.is_open() == false) return false;
    boost::archive::xml_iarchive xml(ifs);

    try
    {
       xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param1value);
       xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param2value);
       xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param3value);
       xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param4value);
    }
    catch(boost::archive::archive_exception e)
    {
       qDebug()<<"Exception: "<<e.what();
    }
    try
    {
       xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(newParam);
    }
    catch(boost::archive::archive_exception e)
    {
       qDebug()<<"New version!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create an integer for version and serialize it first.

```
int param_ver = 1;
xml << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param_ver);
xml << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param1value);
xml << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param2value);
xml << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param3value);
xml << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param4value);
xml << BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param5value);
```

When loading first read the version and use it

```
int param_ver;
xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param_ver);
xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param1value);
xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param2value);
xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param3value);
xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param4value);
if(param_ver>0)
{
  xml >> BOOST_SERIALIZATION_NVP(param5value);
}
```